# Brunch will not compile manifest sass file when dependent sass file changes

Tags: sass, brunch, sass-brunch

I can't get sass compilation to work correctly. If import a sass file into a manifest sass file and make a change to the imported file, only the imported file compiles. The manifest file does not. If I make a change directly to the manifest file, it does compile. I have the project set up like this:

```
├── app
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── assets
│   ├── initialize.js
│   └── scss
│       ├── _base.scss
│       ├── all.scss
├── brunch-config.js
├── package.json
└── public
    ├── README.md
    ├── app.css
    ├── app.css.map
    ├── app.js
    ├── app.js.map
    └── index.html
```

brunch-config:

```
exports.files = {
  javascripts: {joinTo: 'app.js'},
  stylesheets: {
    joinTo: {
      'app.css': 'app/scss/*.scss'
    }
  }
};

exports.paths = {
  watched: ['app']
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "brunch-app",
  "description": "Brunch.io application",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Brunch",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "brunch watch --server",
    "build": "brunch build --production"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "auto-reload-brunch": "^2",
    "brunch": "^2",
    "clean-css-brunch": "^2",
    "sass-brunch": "^2.10.7",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "^2"
  }
}
```

all.scss:

```
@import 'base';
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved as I have the same problem.

Comment: Any updates? Same here